# How to connect to AWS Neptune graph-notebook from JupyterLab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I followed the steps in - https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook , and I was able to run the magic commands from my Mac. But I need to get this configured in JupyterLab.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a new conda env in JupyterLab
2. Installed all required packages in conda env
3. When i run the magic commands like `%status`, I get "UsageError: Line magic function `%status` not found.". Please note that ipython, graph-notebook and all required libraries are installed in conda environment.
4. I skipped the last step in the instruction - `python -m graph_notebook.start_notebook --notebooks-dir ~/notebook/destination/dir`. Running this created a new notebook, which Im unable to access. (Note: JupyterLab is in remote server)

I want to connect to AWS Neptune and visualize graphs in JupyterLab using gremlin queries/magic commands.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `graph-notebook` only supports Jupyter not JupyterLabs, so you will not be able to use the notebook widgets.  There is an open issue on adding support for this, so please +1 this feature request, so we can help prioritize this work. https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/issues/55